# Split string in a column based on character position

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
                Basic Stats        Min       Max      Mean     Stdev   
1        LT50300282010256PAC01   0.336438  0.743478  0.592622  0.052544   
2        LT50300282009269PAC01   0.313259  0.678561  0.525667  0.048047   
3        LT50300282008253PAC01   0.374522  0.746828  0.583513  0.055989   
4        LT50300282007237PAC01  -0.000000  0.749325  0.330068  0.314351   
5        LT50300282006205PAC01  -0.000000  0.819288  0.600136  0.170060
```

and for the column `Basic Stats` I want to retain only the characters between `[9:12]`  so for row 1 I only want to retain `2010` and for row 2 I only want to retain `2009`.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to use

```
df['Basic Stats'] = df['Basic Stats'].map(lambda x: x[9:13])
```

Answer (score 12):

Just use vectorised [`str`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#string-handling) method to slice your strings:

```
In [23]:

df['Basic Stats'].str[9:13]
Out[23]:
0    2010
1    2009
2    2008
3    2007
4    2006
Name: Basic Stats, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [slice](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.slice.html#pandas.Series.str.slice)

```
df["Basic Stats"] = df["Basic Stats"].str.slice(9,13)
```

Output:

```
  Basic Stats       Min       Max      Mean     Stdev
0        2010  0.336438  0.743478  0.592622  0.052544
1        2009  0.313259  0.678561  0.525667  0.048047
2        2008  0.374522  0.746828  0.583513  0.055989
3        2007 -0.000000  0.749325  0.330068  0.314351
4        2006 -0.000000  0.819288  0.600136  0.170060
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
df["Basic Stats"] = [ x[9:13] for x in df["Basic Stats"] ]
```