# Inserting column with specifics

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a specific question: I need to create a column name called "Plane type" for a column that contains the first 4 characters of the "TAIL_NUM" column.

How can I do this? I already imported the data and I can see it.

[image: screenshot of code]

Comment: I think you need to be more specific. There is no `column` type in python. Are you talking about pandas? Something else?

Comment: @martineau added

Comment: @Mark Yes pandas, I added a picture of my code. Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding new column to existing DataFrame in Python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555323/adding-new-column-to-existing-dataframe-in-python-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

Creating new columns with Pandas (assuming that's what you're talking about) is very simple. Pandas also provides common string methods. [Pandas Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html), [Similar SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32213330/split-string-in-a-column-based-on-character-position)

You will use ['string slicing'](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_string_slice.asp) which is worth reading about.

```
df['new_col'] = 'X'
```

or in your case:

```
df['Plane type'] = df['tail_num'].str[:4]
```

Comment: my data frame is called df so how would i include the new column into the already made dataframe? Thankyou

Comment: I saw your code and edited my answer. Good luck new pythonista!

Answer (score 0):

After viewing your code and assuming that the the column `"TAIL_NUM"` have string values, you can do like that:

```
df['Plane type'] = df["TAIL_NUM"].str[0:4]
```

Comment: thanks however it seems to still fail. KeyError: 'tail_num'

Comment: You are sure that the name of the column? this is the column name you told us you want

Comment: show us your data. it will be easy for us to help you(since we don't know the columns names), you can use `display(df.head(5))`  to see the first 5 rows of the data. :)

Comment: Yes. TAIL_NUM is the name of column

Comment: try now, I edited the code

Comment: Cool.  I add to you a beginner guide on the topic: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/05_add_columns.html

please accept my answer if its solved your problem.